# Nuance in the meaning of "and."

Tags: word-meaning, conjunctions

> "It's not the PIIGS one should worry about," Friedman said. "Germany hasn’t even begun falling yet. **And** when Germany falls, *and it will,* that’s when the panic begins to set in."

<sup>([Source](http://www.businessinsider.com/germany-is-the-new-piig-2016-2))</sup>

1. Does the first **'And'** mean "But"?
2. Does *"and it will"* mean "and it will fall for sure"?

Comment: Two things: (1) You need to identify which part of this is confusing to you. (2) When quoting news articles, please provide a link to the source, so that people answering your question can get more context, if needed. See our meta post entitled [Details, please](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) for more tips on asking questions. If you answer those concerns here by editing your question, this can be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

*And* indicates additional information. As in *In addition, when Germany falls...*. This is not equivalent to *but*, which would be used to provide contrasting information.

*And it will* is the speaker's firm prediction that Germany will fall. So yes, the speaker indicates his or her opinion that 'Germany will fall for sure'.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first AND is more of him putting emphasis on the fact that the second and is stating that Germany WILL fall!

"It hasn't even started raining yet.  And when it does, and it will, the ground will be soaked."

The "and" is just emphasis in the certainty of the rain!